# Is this a Philosophical question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Some days ago I have asked [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/148711/is-physics-really-a-rigorous-subject) on MSE but [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17445/why-exactly-has-the-question-been-put-on-hold) it has been said that this question is more of philosophy of science rather than mathematics itself. Though I disagree with this point of view because in my opinion the question is about mathematics and not about meta-math but still I will be very much glad if Philosophy Stack Exchange users give logical reasons supporting any opinion. Specifically, I would like to hear the answer of the following,

> Is the question really not about Mathematics? Is it about Philosophy?

By the way please note that this question has also been asked in Physics Stack Exchange but there also it has been labeled as off-topic.

---

**Added:-**

I didn't post this question in the "Main" because it may not also be suitable for this site also (indeed, as I have mentioned earlier, I don't think this question to be a Philosophical question at all) and so it would do nothing good for the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sub>*I left this post alone for a while because I hoped for an authoritative answer. As there still is none, I will give you my opinion.*</sub>

To be quite honest, if you would ask this question on Philosophy.SE I would leave a comment that this may be better suited at Physics.SE. I probably would not vote to close.

I believe that for this type of questions there exists the soft-question tag on both Math.SE and Physics.SE. When you look at [Physics' help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), section on-topic, there is not really a point this falls under, but it's related to *Accepted and/or actively researched theories* and/or *Mathematics in the context of physics*.

The fact that you received 5 upvotes and 5 close votes suggests the community at Physics.SE is divided on this subject. It would be fair to raise a meta question there to ask for this, I think. Moreover, I'd say you could make a valid point stating that the close reason *primarily opinion based* isn't really applicable in this case.

Before, I stated that when such a question would appear on Philosophy.SE, I would leave a comment but probably not vote to close. Philosophy in some sense gave birth to science, and in that same sense fundamental scientific questions have a sure overlap with philosophy.
It's however not a good idea to ask the same question here as well. Instead, you should flag your question and ask for a migration. You could refer to this page (I'm still hoping for an authoritative answer here) if it helps convincing the moderator reviewing your flag.

> **Disclaimer**: I'm not an active user of Physics.SE nor of Math.SE, do not know their communities or the ins and outs of their ideas on on-topicness.